# PTP support for RTL8125B-CG NIC in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, realtek, ptp

I have an RTL8125B-CG NIC which, from what I gather from [their product page](https://www.realtek.com/en/products/communications-network-ics/item/rtl8125bg-s-cg), has hardware support for PTP. However, `sudo ethtool -T` does not detect any HW timestamping capabilities.

I've tried with the `r8169` driver and with the `r8125` driver from Realtek (both [this one from Github](https://github.com/awesometic/realtek-r8125-dkms) and [this one from Realtek's download page](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software)), but without success. In the Makefile in the source code, there seems to be [a flag which indicate that PTP support is not enabled by default](https://github.com/awesometic/realtek-r8125-dkms/blob/master/src/Makefile#L45), but when I enable this flag I can't compile (I get the error presented in [this issue](https://github.com/awesometic/realtek-r8125-dkms/issues/9)).

Anyone have any experience or know what I can do to get PTP support enabled?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and the `5.11.0-36-generic` kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the issue on Github for an answer: https://github.com/awesometic/realtek-r8125-dkms/issues/9

In short, the issue with compilation was that in the newest version of the driver (9.006.04) Realtek had removed the `spinlock_t lock` member variable from `struct rtl8125_private`, but not updated the PTP file accordingly. Hence, all the `spin_lock_irqsave` and `spin_lock_irqrestore` routines won't compile. There are two ways to fix this:

1. Comment out all of the `spin_lock_irqsave` and `spin_lock_irqrestore` routines in the PTP file, or
2. Add back the `spinlock_t lock` member in the `struct rtl8125_private`.

The latter is probably more safe since we don't know if the IRQs are vital for the function of the driver. That being said, I did try both solutions and both made the driver compile and report PTP HW capabilities, so I don't know which is best.

However, I still think the driver is quite buggy, as I still can't use HW timestamping is slave mode, and I have trouble getting reliable results. I often run into the problem that `ptp4l` from `linuxptp` times out trying to get a timestamp from the driver. I have two different computers with `r8125` NICs, and it works sometimes on one computer and very seldomly on the other. I suspect the PTP function has not been well tested by Realtek, although this is just speculation on my part.

Comment: Hi Eirik, welcome to the community. In order to make your answer more useful for the other members, you should always include at least a summary of the actual solution in your post, and use external links only as a reference. Would you mind editing your answer?

Comment: Of course, sorry! I've updated my answer now. :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Have you got any update on their driver's hardware timestamp accuracy / reliability?